# Is it possible to use a particular thing from jQuery Mobile in a non jQuery Mobile project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a project where I need to make Horizontal touch slider like on this JQM page http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html but I'm not using jQuery Mobile in this project for any other thing.

My question is that Can i use *jQuery Mobile* as a *jQuery plugin* for specific thing in a project where I'm not using jQuery Mobile for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, check here: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: iscroll is way simpler than including the whole jQMobile bundle just for a scroller. I even replaced the jQuery Mobile scrolling with iScroll, because it's way more smooth.

Comment: But iScroll has problem with form elements on iOS and I have form elements and Scroller on same page. That's the reason I don't consider iScroll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771255/select-drop-down-flashing-on-focus-in-iphone-browser-with-iscroll4-script

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a particular thing from jQuery Mobile in a non jQuery Mobile project?

Ans).At the moment-No.

JQM team has hinted at a possible download builder in which you can configure what all widgets you need from JQM to define your own custom version,when RC 1.0 was released.

From the release notes:

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

Reference- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/

But this was not released in 1.0 final.So hopefully we can expect something like this in future versions

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working without jQuery mobile, and it works fine... As long as basic functionality goes...

On line #9 of the script remove the jQuery.mobile.widget argument from jQuery.widget method, I believe that's all that was needed to make it work. My includes are jquery, jquery ui, mobile scrollview and easing.